# Java regular expression: extract filename not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of URL like this one:
`http://mysite.es/img/p/3/6/2/5/6/36256.jpg`

I need to replace the 36256 part.

My regular expression looks like this:

```
Boolean find = Pattern.matches("^[http://].+/(?<number>\\d+)[\\.jpg]$", url);
```

But it's always returning false. What i am doing wrong?
I think the problem is that there are many "/" on the URL but not all the URLs have the same number of /.

This works:

```
Boolean find = Pattern.matches("[\\.jpg]$", url);
```

This doens't works:

```
Boolean find = Pattern.matches("/(\\d+)[\\.jpg]$", url);
```

I can't figure out why.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you know that square brackets denote character classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if your URLs all have "/" characters and a file type extension, you probably don't need regex for this.

For instance:

```
String url = "http://mysite.es/img/p/3/6/2/5/6/36256.jpg";
String toReplace = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, url.lastIndexOf("."));
System.out.println(toReplace);
String replacedURL = url.replace(toReplace, "foo");
System.out.println(replacedURL);
```

**Edit**

```
// solution with regex
Pattern fileName = Pattern.compile(".+(?<!/)/(?!/)(.+?)\\..+?");
Matcher matcher = fileName.matcher(url);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    String replacedURLWithRegex = url.replace(matcher.group(1), "blah");
    System.out.println(replacedURLWithRegex);
}
```

Output:

```
36256
http://mysite.es/img/p/3/6/2/5/6/foo.jpg
```

Output for edit:

```
36256
http://mysite.es/img/p/3/6/2/5/6/blah.jpg
```

About what's wrong in your regex, "[\.jpg]" will attempt to match any character within the class defined by the square brackets, that is "." or "j" or "p" or "g", not ".jpg" in a sequence. For sequential matching you don't use square brackets (although you can use round brackets for grouping sequential matches).

Comment: Thank you again, this was a really big help.

Comment: @CarlosGoce you're welcome. Also added a solution with regex - see my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean

```
Boolean find = Pattern.matches(".*[\\.jpg]$", url);
```

and

```
Boolean find = Pattern.matches(".*/(\\d+)[\\.jpg]$", url);
```

The first pattern matches as it only needs to match any of the characters `.jpg` before the end. The second doesnt match due to fact that it requires a preceding digit before the characters specified in the [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html) positioned at the end of the `URL` `String`.

You need to remove the use of the character class.

```
Boolean find = Pattern.matches(".*/(\\d+)\\.jpg$", url);
```

Comment: I did put two \ symbols. Looks like stackoverflow removed one of each. Sorry my bad English. It works perfect. Thank you very much!